# How can I combine these verbs without repeating the object?

Tags: sentence-construction, repetition

I wrote this sentence

> We show that our proposed system provides robust and maintainable wrappers, which are not tailored to the HTML structure of the page. Therefore, they can be adapted **to similar websites** to gather and integrate information **from various websites**.

*adapt*, *gather* and even *integrate* needs different objects, some of which are similar but the whole meaning of each combination is different, then how can I combine them?

For example can I say:

> Therefore, they can be adapted to gather and integrate information from various websites.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I think you're worrying too much about repeating words. Sometimes you just have to repeat them, no matter what.

Comment: I would simply omit the first website phrase altogether.  Something like "Therefore they can be adapted to gather and integrate information from various websites."  The idea that code is not unique to a particular job is sort of assumed in programming.

Comment: You can eliminate "to similar websites" and alter "from various websites" to "from almost any website".

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this sentence

> Therefore, they can be adapted to similar websites for gathering [and integrating] information.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repetition (in your case *preposition-adjective-"websites"*) you could modify one of the phrases (by adding a word, for instance) to break the pattern, so to speak:

> Therefore, they can be adapted **to similar websites** to gather and integrate information **from various *other* websites**.

The other way to avoid repeating yourself is to replace the noun, of course.  For instance, you can replace 'websites' with 'collection of pages' in the first phrase:

> Therefore, they can be adapted **to similar *collections of pages*** to gather and integrate information **from various websites**.